# Does jsfiddle import knockout & backbone automatically ?

Tags: backbone.js, knockout.js, jsfiddle

Looking at this fiddle which uses knockout and backbone, are these libraries being automatically imported ?

[backbone and knockout fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geekdave/bjUBq/)

```
Code here : 

Name: <input data-bind="value: name" type="text"/><br>
Age: <input data-bind="value: age" type="text"/><br>
Evil: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: evil" /><br>

<button id="foo">Change Model!</button>

// create a plain old backbone model
var backboneModel = new Backbone.Model({
    name: "Montgomery Burns",
    age: 102,
    evil: true
});

// use knockback.js to bridge knockout data-binding with backbone models
// read_only is set to false to make the binding two-way.
// note the use of the "kb" api for knockback.
var viewModel = kb.viewModel(backboneModel, {
    read_only: false
});

// at this point, knockback has given us a viewModel which is compatible
// with the normal knockout api.  so we can use the "ko" api now.
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$("#foo").click(function() {
    backboneModel.set ({
        "name": "Lisa Simpson",
        "age": 8,
        "evil": false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've been included by the author of the fiddle using the **Manage resources** feature in the left sidebar.